# Android List item background "grey out" effect

Tags: android, listview

How can I get the gmail like ListView feature in Android. I mean when I click on particular list item, it should change its background color (grey out) so that user can know that this item has been already clicked and it should retain its state.

Is there any simple feature in Android to implement this? I know I can change the background color of my layout but when I scroll the list is recycled and also the list item state. So how can I do it?

Here is an image what for better understanding:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set the background of the list item to a [State List drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). If you set this on every item, the state list will automatically do what you want.

Comment: Thanks.... but this is not what i want . I have already tested it and it is not working because this will only work for the currently selected item . I want the feature just link any mail app means when item get selected it show retain its state till the application is  closed.

Comment: Did you try `state_checked` with the `ListView` set to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` filled with `CheckedTextView`s?

Answer (score 0):

Use HashMap to store which item the user has selected and set background depending on the user selection

### Example

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyListView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Context context = null;
    HashMap<String, Boolean> userSelectionMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PENS);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        this.registerForContextMenu(lv);




    }



    static final String[] PENS = new String[]{
        "MONT Blanc",
        "Gucci",
        "Parker",
        "Sailor",
        "Porsche Design",
        "item1",
        "item2",
        "item3",
        "item4",
        "item5",
        "item6",




    };

   @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    System.out.println("...selected...");
    if(isItemSelectedBefore(""+position)){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whbk);
    }else{
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grbk);
    }
}

  boolean isItemSelectedBefore(String position){
      boolean userSelection = false;
      if(userSelectionMap.containsKey(position)){
          userSelection = !userSelection;
      }
      userSelectionMap.put(position, userSelection);
    return userSelectionMap.get(position);

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when i scroll the list will it show the previously selected items and also i don't want the list item to change its background when it is clicked again.

Comment: then just you have to make very little change. use the following code  boolean isItemSelectedBefore(String position){
       userSelectionMap.put(position, true);
     return true;

    }

Comment: as the ListView recycled itself when we scroll so the listitem not retaining its state . i mean the background color changed to random list item.